# mini-batch gradient descent, loss doesn't improve and accuracy very low

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, iris-dataset, mini-batch

I’m trying to implement mini-batch gradient descent on the popular iris dataset, but somehow I don’t manage to get the accuracy of the model above 75-80%. Also the loss does not decrease and is rather stuck at around 0.45, even when I set the number of iterations to 10000.
Something im missing here ?

```
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_stack =  nn.Sequential(
         nn.Linear(4,128),
         nn.ReLU(),
         nn.Linear(128,64),
         nn.ReLU(),
         nn.Linear(64,3),
         )
    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.linear_stack(x)
        return logits
```

training loop, batchsize per epoch = 10.
transform_label maps [0,1,2] to the labels.

```
lr = 0.01
model = NeuralNetwork()
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

n_iters = 1000
steps = n_iters/10
LOSS = []
for epochs in range(n_iters):  
    for i,(inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        out = model(inputs)
        train_labels = transform_label(labels)
        l = loss(out, train_labels)
        l.backward()
        #update weights
        optim.step()
        optim.zero_grad()
    LOSS.append(l.item())
    if epochs%steps == 0:
        print(f"\n epoch: {int(epochs+steps)}/{n_iters}, loss: {sum(LOSS)/len(LOSS)}")
        #if i % 1 == 0:
            #print(f" steps: {i+1}, loss : {l.item()}")
```

output:

> epoch: 100/1000, loss: 1.0636296272277832

> epoch: 400/1000, loss: 0.5142968013338076

> epoch: 500/1000, loss: 0.49906910391073867

> epoch: 900/1000, loss: 0.4586030915751588

> epoch: 1000/1000, loss: 0.4543738731996598

Is it possible to calculate the loss like that or should I use torch.max()? If I do so I get this Error:

> Expected floating point type for target with class probabilities, got Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't provide enough data and code to reproduce the problem. I wrote a complete and working code to train your model on the IRIS dataset.

Imports and Classes.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
import pandas as pd
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        assert len(X) == len(Y)
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X)
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        x = self.X[item]
        y = self.Y[item]
        return x, y

class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear_stack =  nn.Sequential(
         nn.Linear(4,128),
         nn.ReLU(),
         nn.Linear(128,64),
         nn.ReLU(),
         nn.Linear(64,3),
         )
    def forward(self, x):
        logits = self.linear_stack(x)
        return logits
```

Read and Preprocess the data.

```
# Dataset was downloaded from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/
df = pd.read_csv("iris.data", names=["x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "label"])
X, Y = df[['x1', "x2", "x3", "x4"]], df['label']

# First, we transform the labels to numbers 0,1,2
encoder = LabelEncoder()
Y = encoder.fit_transform(Y)

# We split the dataset to train and test
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

# Due to the nature of Neural Networks, we standardize the inputs to get better results
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

train_dataset = MyDataset(X_train, Y_train)
test_dataset = MyDataset(X_test, Y_test)

train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=8)
```

Train the model.

```
lr = 0.01
model = NeuralNetwork()
optim = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

n_iters = 1000
steps = n_iters/10
LOSS = []

for epochs in range(n_iters):  
    for i,(inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        optim.zero_grad()
        out = model(inputs.float())
        l = loss(out, labels)
        l.backward()
        optim.step()
    LOSS.append(l.item())
    if epochs%steps == 0:
        print(f"\n epoch: {int(epochs+steps)}/{n_iters}, loss: {sum(LOSS)/len(LOSS)}")
```

*output:*
[image: trainin_output]

Then, we need to run the model on test data to calculate the metrics.

```
preds = []
with torch.no_grad():
    for i,(inputs, labels) in enumerate(test_loader):
        out = model(inputs.float())
        preds.extend(list(torch.argmax(out, axis=1).cpu().numpy()))
```

To get the metrics, you can use "[classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)".

```
print(classification_report(y_true=Y_test, y_pred=preds))
```

*output:*
[image: metrics]

I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the effort. Your answer helps a lot. At first, I thought maybe because I didn't scale the input like you did with "scaler = StandardScaler()", but even when removing this part, it still produces better results. Somehow it has to do with how im loading the data I guess, your way of doing so seems way more efficient and easier. I tried to follow this guide : https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html. However, I'm very thankful for your answer!